# Kohana 3.3 ORM::factory('foo', $id) does not load model, missing something?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Model_Job extends ORM
{
    public $ID;

    public $user_ID;
    public $title;
    //some more variables
}
```

In my controller I have a function `action_view()`; view job details single job, implemented exactly like http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/using#finding-an-object

```
public function action_view()
{
    $this->render('Shit');
    $this->template->content = View::factory('jobs/job')
                                    ->bind('job', $job);

    $job = ORM::factory('job', $this->request->param('id'));                    
}
```

I have another function `action_all()` which simply fetches all jobs using `find_all` and puts them on the page, this works great (meaning `echo $job->ID` does what it should do; echo the ID. However `action_view()` does not. I'll place some the output of `echo Debug::vars($job)`

```
object Model_Job(39) {
    public ID => NULL //Note they are NULL
    public user_ID => NULL 
    public title => NULL
    ......................
    protected _object => array(5) (
        "ID" => string(1) "1"
        "user_ID" => string(1) "1"
        "title" => string(14) "Testbaantjeeee"
        ................
    )
    .....................
 }
```

Whereas an example of an `echo Debug::vars($job)` from `action_all()` would look like:

```
object Model_Job(39) {
    public ID => 1 //Note they are NOT NULL
    public user_ID => 1
    public title => "Testbaantjeeee"
    ......................
    protected _object => array(5) (
        "ID" => string(1) NULL       //now these are NULL
        "user_ID" => string(1) NULL
        "title" => string(14) NULL
        .....................
    )
    .....................
 }
```

I looked in kohena's documentation about `factory`, `find`, `find_all` etc. but could not figure out what `factory` or `find` is NOT doing what `find_all` is doing. Am I missing something? I got it working using:

```
$job = ORM::factory('job')
           ->where('ID', '=', $this->request->param('id'))
           ->find_all()[0];
```

But doing that makes absolutely no sense to me. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to set `$_primary_key` property with 'ID' value. See http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#property:_primary_key

Comment: Also, can you show your model code? I dont understand, why do you need that public fields (ID, user_ID etc), while ORM allows you to access them "out of the box".

Comment: `$job->object()['title']` This works, `protected _primary_key => string(2) "ID" public ID => NULL` did not change anything. That is my model code, there are some more properties but there are no methods or anything.

Comment: There is no needs for table fields like ID. Just use `$job->title`, `$job->ID` (or `$job->id()`) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I went ahead and worked around it.

I created a class `Model_Base`

```
class Model_Base extends ORM
{
    public function Load()
    {
        foreach($this->object() as $key => $value)
            if(!is_object($value))
                if(property_exists(get_class($this), $key))
                    $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Now I extend all my models from here

```
class Model_Job extends Model_Base
{
    ..................
}
```

And now my controller uses this:

```
public function action_view()
{
    $this->render('Shit');
    $this->template->content = View::factory('jobs/job')
                                    ->bind('job', $job);

    $job = ORM::factory('job', $this->request->param('id'));
    $job->Load();
}
```

And it dumps:

```
object Model_Job(39) {
    protected _primary_key => string(2) "ID"
    public ID => string(1) "1"
    public user_ID => string(1) "1"
    public title => string(14) "Testbaantjeeee"
    ......................
}
```

I still think it makes no sense. But whatever. If anyone knows why they made `find()/factory('foo', $id)` and `find_all()` so fundamentally different that the former is useless, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a different key for your id, it is capitalized ID. Make sure in your model to set

```
protected $_primary_key = 'ID';
```

Because following your example, both methods just should echo exactly the same.